# How to hide duplicate column caused by groupingValueGetter in Material-UI DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

As you can see in the following code sand box:
https://codesandbox.io/s/row-grouping-li67j6?file=/demo.tsx:696-764

There are two "Datetime" columns. The second column has "Invalid Date" as the group header, I would like to hide this unnecessary column. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I'm using `"@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.21"` and `"react": "^16.13.1"`

Answer (score 1):

```
const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
    apiRef,
    initialState: {
      rowGrouping: {
        model: ["datetime"]
      }
    }
  });
  const rows = generateMockData();
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPremium
        columns={columns}
        rows={rows}
        apiRef={apiRef}
        initialState={initialState}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below you can see the edited forked sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/row-grouping-forked-26sjgh?file=/demo.tsx:1186-1588

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however from your code sandbox, it seems like when you expand a group the rows for the datetime column are no longer visible. However, the rows for the id column is still there.